# Spring Security 3: Preventing authentication filters on specific URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies, spring-security

I'm having trouble with some authentication issues regarding Spring Security 3. In my web application the users are not logging in through the usual form. Users are entering to another web application where they log in and from there they have access to a link that opens my web app's main page. Please mind that all this architecture is within the same company and the user database is common to all apps.
The other web app sends the already logged in username through POST data, which I can get by doing `request.getParameter("username")`. The controller that handles that URL post request gets the username and forces that user to be logged in, using this code:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(usuario.getRole());
UserDetails userDetails = new User(usuario.getLogin(), "undefined", authorities);
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Other relevant code is the `applicationContext-security.xml`:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/ShowDocuments" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/AddDocForm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/AccessDenied"/>
        <http-basic/>

        <session-management invalid-session-url="/InvalidSessionURL" session-authentication-error-url="/SessionAuthenticationErrorURL">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" 
                                 expired-url="/ExpiredURL" />
        </session-management>
        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="false"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager></authentication-manager>
```

The problem is that the first time any user gets to my main page they are redirected to the "invalidSessionURL". Despite this not being what I wanted, this is what I should have expected, since the first time any user tries to access any page in my security context it must go through the authentication process and filters, and at that time the system doesn't have any way to identify that user. This happens if I follow this procedure:

1. I clean all temp files that my browser might have stored.
2. I open ShowDocuments URL, which is my main page (in my test environment this action forces a mocked user to be logged in once the controller handles the request).
3. The "invalidSessionURL" is shown.

If I don't clean the browser's temp files but my cookie has expired (in my test environment its validity is set to 1 minute), the same thing happens, because the cookie is no longer valid.

The question is the following: is there any way to avoid Spring Security to check authentication when anyone goes to my main page "ShowDocuments"? I tried this `<http pattern="/ShowDocuments" security="none"/>` with no success...

Comment: How does your server know the post request comes from the trusted other web application and not from another source?

Comment: All servers and clients are within a private company network, so that's not really relevant right now. I know this approach is not safe, but considering the circumstances what I need is the web app to be up and running as soon as possible.

Comment: It *is* relevant, the source need not be a rogue server, it can be any user's browser and they can simply start the application pretending they're someone else!

Comment: That's not the problem I'm try to solve. Please, if you have any clue for question asked just share it here for everybody. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking for help in effectively ripping the authentication out of your application, expect some protestations :) Do you have an ordinary login page too or is /ShowDocuments with user param the only way to authenticate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Security and logging in from another site without reentering credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398895/spring-security-and-logging-in-from-another-site-without-reentering-credentials)

Comment: That post's initial goal was different (before the edit), so after solving the main issue by myself I faced another problem. Instead of opening then a different question, which I should had done from the beginning, I do it now. Regarding your question, there is no login form or page: /ShowDocuments is the only way.

Comment: Does your company have an ADS server and are the users logged in to the OS? If so, you can use the Windows authentication. See http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue with login page, adding whildcard to path solved my issue:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll()" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not working for me. The same situation I explained keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html) to grab the user parameter from the request. In your AuthenticationManager, specify a [PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.html) that looks up the user details in the shared database using a [AuthenticationUserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/AuthenticationUserDetailsService.html).

You really ought to use a secure mechanism that lets the trusted authenticating server assert that it has checked the user's credentials.